# Como organizar o css e o js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Adquiri um template free e estou aplicando na minha página principal do blog. Criei um administrativo para esse blog e estou com uma dúvida se minha organização dos assets está correta. Segue a estrutura:

app/assets/javascripts:
  
  admin

  template

  admin.js  //faz a chamada do dir admin, funciona normalmente

  application.js

E a chamada dentro do application.js está assim:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require template/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js
//= require template/js/skel.min.js
//= require template/js/init.js
```

app/assets/stylesheets:
  
  admin

  template

  admin.css  //faz a chamada do dir admin, funciona normalmente

  application.css

E a chamada dentro do application.css está assim:

```
*= require template/css/skel.css
*= require template/css/style.css
*= require template/css/style-xlarge.css
*= require_self
```

e no layout application.html.haml faço a referencia do application.css e application.js. A minha dúvida é se essa organização é a correta pq estava lendo no guide e vejo que tem a pasta public e vendor para css e js mas não sei quando utilizar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antigamente rails colocava imagens, css e javascript em public realmente, mas atualmente é aconselhado utilizar a pasta assets para esses arquivos:

> In previous versions of Rails, all assets were located in
>   subdirectories of public such as images, javascripts and stylesheets.

[Documentação](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Já a organização dentro da pasta assets pode ficar da seguinte forma (como descrito na documentação enviada em 2.2 Asset Organization)

app/assets para os assets da própria aplicação.

lib/assets para suas bibliotecas próprias, e que não se encaixam no escopo da aplicação ou de bibliotecas compartilhadas com outra aplicação

vendor/assets é para assets pertencentes a entidades externas, como plugins de javascript e frameworks css. códigos que fazem referencias a outros arquivos aqui precisam ser adaptados para utilizar helpers como asset_path.

Vale dizer os assets colocados em public ainda funcionam e são servidos como arquivos  estáticos dependendo das suas configurações. Os arquivos em assets são automaticamente servidos, após serem pré-compilados, em public/assets quando em produção.

> In production, Rails precompiles these files to public/assets by
>   default. The precompiled copies are then served as static assets by
>   the web server. The files in app/assets are never served directly in
>   production.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback deu para entender como funciona. Mas a chamada nos arquivos application estão da forma correta?

Comment: não vejo motivos para estar errado, normalmente eu usaria os css/scss e js/coffee gerados pelo rails para os controllers mesmo, você chama cada arquivo diretamente no html?

Comment: No HTML chamo apenas o application.JS e o application.CSS ou seja não mudei nada, deixei da mesma forma que o rails criou.

Comment: O ideal é não chamar nenhum arquivo diretamente, apenas usar o `javascript_include_tag :application` e `stylesheet_link_tag :application` e deixar que o rails controle quais arquivos adicionar em quais páginas

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se isto ira responder a sua pergunta, porem servirá como um sugestão.

Atualmente eu utilizo o Grunt Js (http://gruntjs.com/) para: Minificar (css, javascript); concatenar diversos arquivo em somente um; "compilar o código jquery".

Ele possui diversos plugins (http://gruntjs.com/plugins), que te dão a possibilidade de criar diversas formas de automação.

Ele trabalha com base no NodeJs (http://nodejs.org/).

Um passo a passo em português, http://www.voltsdigital.com.br/labs/gruntjs-por-onde-comecar/ , que ensina por onde começar e dá algumas dicas de plugins e configuração.

Comment: Eu conheço o grunt. Mas minha duvida é sobre a organização dentro do rails. Mas obrigado pelo feedback.